# How to fix 'Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables' error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am attempting a problem that can be solved with MUC (method of undetermined coefficients).

However, when I use the Solve function, it gives an error.

```js
y[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d
Solve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + y[x] == x^3}, {a, b, c, d}]

[ERROR]:
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
```

Shouldn't this solve for all variables in the set?

Thank You for your help :)

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Solve/svars.html

Comment: Thank You for the link. However, the documentation does not describe a fix for my use case. I am assuming that Solve does not apply the method of undetermined coefficients, as the 'svars' error states that there has to be an equal or greater amount of equalities (but undetermined coefficients can be found using the method described).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [some extra methodology](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/differential-equations/second-order-equations/the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients) is needed for this.

As you stated, a function with the finite family of derivatives for `x^3` is

```
y[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d
```

Equating coefficients

```
sol = Solve[Thread[CoefficientList[
     y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + y[x], x] == CoefficientList[x^3, x]]]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 1, b -> -6, c -> 18, d -> -24}}
> ```

Checking the results

```
FullSimplify[y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + y[x] == x^3 /. sol]
```

> ```
> {True}
> ```

Comment: I just tried this; it doesn't work. It is returning solutions with reference to the variables I am trying to solve for.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thank You. This answer explains a few things. Mathematica clearly needs explicit definition of certain mathematical scenarios, rather than being able to automatically identify these types of questions automatically. A shame indeed, considering I use this software in high school and limited CAS training is provided, so programmatic solutions are a lot less desirable (although I am a software developer myself!).

Comment: Yes, it's a interesting example of needing to know technique.  I'm sure there are lots of examples but here's an old one I remember well, trying to plot `Sin[x^2*y]==Log[x/y]` :- http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/May/msg00021.html